# Загрузка нескольких файлов сразу в Gwt.

Tags: gwt, java, upload

Я новичок в Gwt. Пользуюсь стандартной компонентой FileUpload. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать несколько файлов сразу и зааплоадить их на сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую проанализировать [демо](http://aariadne.com/uploadform/) с помощью окна разработчика (посмотреть код элементов).

Класс FormPanel разворачивается в элемент < form >. А класс FileUpload разворачивается в элемент

```
<input type="file">
```

В примере есть несколько пар form & input (file). Они не видны снаружи, пользователю подсовывается другой UI. Поэтому чтобы реализовать это с помощью GWT, нужно иметь несколько пар FileUpload & FormPanel и список уже загруженных файлов (на VerticalPanel, например). Каждый раз, когда пользователь будет выбирать новый файл, мы будем добавлять еще одну пару FileUpload & FormPanel и подставлять юзеру для клика новый, еще не имеющий значения, input. Потом, когда пользователь жмет ОК (Submit), мы отправляем последовательно все наши формы (FormPanel). Потом слушаем SubmitCompleteEvent-ы, и когда он придет N раз (кол-во файлов), то можно считать, что мы зааплоадили все файлы.

Выбирать сразу несколько файлов и отправлять мы не сможем. То есть для того, чтобы мы могли в диалоге выбрать несколько файлов, нужно написать всего одну проперть, но отправляться будет только первый файл. И, по-моему, заставить работать форму по-другому никак нельзя. Для этого уже надо использовать action script.

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей мы в своем проекте используем [GWT Upload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/Downloads?tm=2).
В библиотеке есть класс MultipleUploader, который позволяет
пользователю поочередно выбирать несколько файлов:
пока первый файл отправляется второй стоит в очереди.

Насчет одновременного выбора нескольких файлов и пересылки их одним запросом
- думаю это возможно.
Попробуйте изменить исходный код GWT Upload под свои нужды,
мы так часто делаем.

Что касается передачи файлов в несколько запросов - будте осторожны,
т.к. браузер разрешает программисту установить лишь два соединения с сервером.
При игнорировании этого правила Internet Explorer может зависнуть.

Comment: @Ivan Golubev думаю, насчет выбора нескольких файлов и пересылки их одним запросом вы ошибаетесь.